# EXCEL - pulling unique values from a range that fit specific criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, unique-values

I am using the following array formula in excel to pull unique values from a range.

```
{=INDEX($N$2:$N$21, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$385:A399, $N$2:$N$21), 0))}
```

That works fine, however I want to pull specific values based on criteria.

The data I am working with is formatted as: | Names | Team | Site | Date |  and I want to pull unique values from the names column that match my team and site criteria within a date range.

I am getting the date range with the following:

```
{=CELL("address",INDEX($A2:$D50000,MATCH(TRUE,$D2:$D50000>=$B$1,0),4))}
```

reversing for end date, then using those values to populate my index / countif ranges in my first formula with INDIRECT. Again, this is all working. I just can't seem to get my criteria to work to make my unique values only pull when part of X team and Y site.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.